# How to change CSS with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following HTML generated dynamically by PHP.
When I click active, it changed to inactive and vise versa.

I added div class='status' for jquery manipulation. (Do I need it? Can I do it without this div?)

I want to change CSS class='status' to class='inactive' when I click active and when I click inactive changing CSS class to 'active' as well, so that I can change a color or add bg image etc.

HTML

```
...
...    
<tr valign='top'>
  <td align='center'>21</td>
  <td>Kontakt</td>
  <td>/kontakt.html</td>
  <td align='center'>
     <div class="status">
       <a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/21">active</a>
     </div>
  </td>
  <td align='center'>...
  ...
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am using jquery and I need some guidance.

Can anyone tell me some jquery code please?

--UPDATE--

There are many div with calss='status', so how can I tell jquery that I want to change the css which I clicked.

--UPDATE 2--

I want to check the value(active/inactive). And add it's value as class. e.x If its value is active, then add css class='active' and if it is inactive then  class='inactive' etc.
Can I do it?
Or you have other suggestions how I should do it.

--UPDATE 3--

Thanks everyone. You guys rock. I tested some of codes. But the problem is that when I click active, it change the bg, but then refreshes the page to change to inactive via php/mysql. So this means each time I click the value(active/inactive) changes. So I think as I stated in update 2, it might be good idea to add css class depends on the value. 
More suggestions are welcome and I appreciate them. (I have not done it with AJAX yet...)

--UPDATE 4 --

Using ID is not a good idea since the table is created dynamically. I can add IDs but it will add more code. So I thought class is better.

--UPDATE 5--

I moved my question here. [How to add a class depends on value with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909223/how-to-add-a-class-depends-on-value-with-jquery)

After this, I now know what I want to do.

Comment: You'll want to live bind those elements (especially if none of them will have ids). Live binding makes it such that all present and future elements that match the selector will be selected. Further reading: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Comment: Re your update about how to tell jQuery which code you clicked, you need to trigger the toggle code from an onclick event on some entity within your code (e.g. a div or anchor ref). If you then use the standard 'this' selector, the toggle operation won't be "greedy" (i.e. it won't toggle *all* the stuff in your page classed as "active" or whatever)

Comment: re: your second update - assuming you are binding via event handler (which you should!) then within that you can do something like var value = $(this).text(); and do conditionals off of that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery has functions toggleclass(),  removeClass() and addClass(). These should help you along.

Without seeing the whole HTML its a bit difficult to suggest a selector. If you assigned an id to your div (e.g. mydiv) then you could have

```
$("#mydiv").removeClass('status').addClass('inactive');
```

Or just to flip them regardless:

```
$("#mydiv").toggleClass('status').toggleClass('inactive');
```

This makes use of chaining quite nicely

Comment: I think this one is closest to optimum so far as it uses the 'id' attribute.  I would prefer `toggleClass()`  to either of the other two.  However, I would only apply it to the 'inactive' class.  CSS allows an element to have two (or  more) classes, so the two states would be 'status' and 'status inactive'.  Then the active CSS styling goes into the CSS class for '.status' and the inactive styling goes in the CSS class for '.inactive'.  Care must be taken to ensure that the '.inactive' rules overrule the '.status' rules in the cascade.

Comment: I agree with you re: the css cascading. However, I think it makes less sense to use ids in this situation because it looks like the situation is a dynamic list of content with repeating structure.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to your first question, you could probably move that class onto the enclosing `<td />` (although background images don't always play nice there).

To add/remove a class with jquery, you can do something like so:

```
$('div.status').addClass('inactive');
$('div.status').removeClass('status');
```

Or, if you want it fired on a click use `toggleClass`

```
$('div.status', 'div.inactive').live("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("inactive").toggleClass("status");
        });
```

This will also only fire on the specific div.status (or inactive) that you click.

Answer (score 1):

[.addClass()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass)
[.removeClass()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass)

EDIT: In reponse to your update, you can have an onclick() function in your div that will change the class for that particular div.

```
<div onclick="changeClass" id="myId"></div>
function changeClass() { 
   $(this).toggleClass('status').toggleClass('inactive'); 
}
```

Please test that code, but I think that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Don't forget, you can use chaining, so just chain the second toggleClass at the end of the first!

Comment: Yes, good point! I also like ddango's answer, to attach the .click() function to every .status and .inactive div.

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest solution would be to use the in-built toggle functions in jQuery, which will let you toggle the status of your specified classes using the standard jQuery selector syntax:

```
$(this).toggleClass("inactive");
```

See the [doc page](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass) for more

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the div, which you asked about, you can remove it and select all links within a td (or add a class to specific td tags and adjust selector: $('td.status') to narrow down selection to just those).

```
//Click Handler to toggle active state of all links descendant of all td tags
$("td a").click(function(){
 //add/remove inactive class and add/remove active smoothly over 1/2 second in total
 $(this).toggleClass("inactive, 250").toggleClass("active", 250);
});
```

> *NOTE*:
>
> $("td a") will select all a tag descendants. To only get children a tags of td:

```
$("td > a")
```