# How to add a class depends on value with jquery

Tags: jquery, class

From my question [How to change CSS with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908889/how-to-change-css-with-jquery), I now understant what I need to learn and what I want to do.

I want to add class active or inactive depends on the value with jquery.

For example changing

```
<td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/21">active</a></td>
```

to

```
<td align='center'><a class="active"  href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/21">active</a></td>
```

and

```
<td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/15">inactive</a></td>
```

to

```
<td align='center'><a class="inactive" href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/15">inactive</a></td>
```

The following HTML is generated dynamically. When I click, active, inactive, edit and delete, the page is reloaded.

```
...
...
<tr valign='top'>

<td align='center'>21</td>
<td>Kontakt</td>
<td>/kontakt.html</td><td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/21">active</a></td>
<td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/edit/21">edit</a> | <a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/delete/21">delete</a></td>
</tr>
<tr valign='top'>
<td align='center'>15</td>
<td>Web Design Tjenester</td>

<td>/webdesigndetails.html</td><td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/15">inactive</a></td>
<td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/edit/15">edit</a> | <a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/delete/15">delete</a></td>
</tr>
<tr valign='top'>
<td align='center'>5</td>
<td>Forsiden</td>
<td>/forsiden.html</td><td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/5">active</a></td>

<td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/edit/5">edit</a> | <a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/delete/5">delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why did I get minus? Explain it please.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a:contains('active'), a:contains('inactive')").each(function() 
{ 
    $(this).addClass($(this).text()); 
});
```

Perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You could put your default class in, then toggle another class (activeClass) such as

```
$('a').click(function(myevent) {
    $(this).toggleClass('activeClass');
    myevent.preventDefault();// if you do not want the link to be activated...
});
```

Note that you do not really need a link 'a' element, for this if you are preventing defaults and a div with text or an image element in it might be better - it has no default you would need to prevent.  You could then inject the html in the div with the .html() jQuery or text with the .text().

EDIT1:  One other tidbit, you can detect the class automatically using the .hasClass('active') such as:

```
$(this).click(function()
{
   if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
   {
    // do what you want here
   };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick if you want to set class to the links depending on their text.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
  <style>
    .inactive
    {
    color: red;
    }

    .active
    {
    color: green;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   // ensure that the jquery and the page contents has 
   // been loaded, and run the class adding script
   $(document).ready
   (
    function()
    {
     // get all links, and iterate trough them
     $('a').each
     (
      function (index, value)
      {
       // set the class of each item to be equal to its text (or inner html)
       $(value).addClass($(value).html());
      }
     )
    }
   );
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <table>
   <tr valign='top'>
    <td align='center'>21</td>
    <td>Kontakt</td>
    <td>/kontakt.html</td><td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/21">active</a></td>
    <td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/edit/21">edit</a> | <a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/delete/21">delete</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr valign='top'>
    <td align='center'>15</td>
    <td>Web Design Tjenester</td>
    <td>/webdesigndetails.html</td><td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/15">inactive</a></td>
    <td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/edit/15">edit</a> | <a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/delete/15">delete</a></td>
   </tr>
    <tr valign='top'>
    <td align='center'>5</td>
    <td>Forsiden</td>
    <td>/forsiden.html</td><td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/changePageStatus/5">active</a></td>
    <td align='center'><a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/edit/5">edit</a> | <a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/admin/pages/delete/5">delete</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you wish to change the class of the table row depending on the text of the link (it seems more logical to me), you can use
 $(value).parent().parent().addClass($(value).html());

instead of

 $(value).addClass($(value).html());